# Inconsistent state when debuging with IDEA

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, hive

I'm trying to debug Hive with IDEA, but the thread-local variables changed after I step into some function (without actually executed any code in the current thread).

Here's a snapshot of what happened:
1. At line 1986, all threads was suspended, and the `Thread.currentThread().threadLocals.size` was 23.
[image]

2. Then I `step into` that function:
   [image]

The current thread didn't do anything at all, but the `Thread.currentThread().threadLocals.size` changed to 26.

I know I'm debugging a multi-threading program, but the threadLocal variables here should not change at all.

Could anyone explain to me what may happened here please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you stopping ALL threads or just CURRENT thread?

Comment: ALL threads. And I think other threads could not change the threadlocal variables of the current thread, right?

Comment: Maybe you are suspending only current thread huh?

Comment: What are the three objects that get added to the threadLocals? Why does it matter?

Comment: I tried both ALL and thread, and got the same result

Comment: One of them is the rpc `callId`, and this caused the hive-server to crash, this is how i found this problem

Comment: I cannot see how an 'rpc' can cause the hive-server to crash. I also don't really see what it has to do with your threadLocal. Where threadLocals gets changed isn't necessarily the thread that is running. Logically it seems like it should be, but there doesn't appear any documentation to assure that.

Comment: And based on ThreadLocal's code, I don't see why other threads could change the threadlocal variable of the current thread

Comment: Hive server would create HDFS session dirs with HDFS client at start-up, this is the code why the callId would crash hive-server `Preconditions.checkState(callId.get() == null); ` . HDFS client did this check when trying to start a rpc call, and the `callId` is the threadlocal variable changed